# Softmax for basic logistic classifier- Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am working on a basic Neural network classifier. The goal is to train a NN based on a 3-label group of data, and then predict values. The data schematic is as follows: [image]

My code gives garbage answers. Any suggestions?

The current code is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#increased the number of epoch
epochs = 100000
# For eq100tion y = b + 0.1, sample data below
myImportedDatax1_np = np.array([[.1],[.1],[.2],[.2],[.3],[.3],[.4],[.4],[.1],[.1],[.2],[.2],],dtype=float)
myImportedDatax2_np = np.array([[.1],[.2],[.1],[.2],[.3],[.4],[.3],[.4],[.3],[.4],[.3],[.4]],dtype=float)
combined_Imported_Data_x = np.append(myImportedDatax1_np, myImportedDatax2_np, axis=1)
myImportedDatay_np = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],dtype=int)

number_unique_labels = myImportedDatay_np.max()+1 
myImportedDatay_np_one_hot = np.zeros((myImportedDatay_np.size, number_unique_labels))

myImportedDatay_np_one_hot[np.arange(myImportedDatay_np.size),myImportedDatay_np] = 1

print(myImportedDatay_np_one_hot)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2], name='x')

y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, number_unique_labels], name='y_true')

nodes_Hidden_Layer_1 = 6
number_Inputs = 2
number_Outputs = 3

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([number_Inputs, nodes_Hidden_Layer_1], stddev=0.03), name='W1')
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes_Hidden_Layer_1]), name='b1')
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes_Hidden_Layer_1, number_Outputs], stddev=0.03), name='W2')
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([number_Outputs]), name='b2')

hidden_out = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W1), b1)
hidden_out = tf.nn.relu(hidden_out)

y_ = (tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_out, W2), b2))

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_))

optimiser = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.7).minimize(cost)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # initialise the variables
    sess.run(init_op)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        _, cost_now = sess.run([optimiser, cost], {x: combined_Imported_Data_x, y_true: myImportedDatay_np_one_hot})
    print("Predicted values are:")
    print(sess.run(y_, {x: combined_Imported_Data_x}))
```

Comment: You are stating in your question that you want to create a 'logistic classifier' but instead it appears that you are doing more of a linear regression. Are you sure about which one specifically you need? If it is indeed a classifier, then why are you attempting to have only one output with non-binary values? Wouldn't it make more sense to have a 3-point output and have your true labels as 0, 1, and 2, and then convert them to one-hot vectors and then use SoftMax + Cross Entropy to train the model?

Comment: okay, I see your point.

Comment: I have changed the code to a conventional logistic classifier. However, I am not getting the correct answer using softmax. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are almost there. A couple of things missing/etc. I will post in the answer space, because not enough space here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in a nutshell, what was missing from your code is the following:

- In the end you are trying to print `y_`, but that's raw out put from
  your neurons that you can't interpret easily, that's why it looks like garbage, but essentially it is correct.
- You need to pass that raw output through `softmax` in order to squash it into something that can be interpreted as probabilities. Your code DOES put it through `softmax` with the call to `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, but that ends up in a separate branch of the graph, which is not what you are printing for your own eyes -- TF gets it for the `cost` calculation, but you don't see it
- So, simply run the raw output through `softmax` separately, and then take `argmax` of that output. `Argmax` gives you the index of the largest element in your input, so basically the class that you are looking for. THAT'S ultimately what you need to look at as your predicted value.
- If you print the output of your predictions step by step, you will see that the networks "learns" (essentially memorizes) what it
  needs    to do around the 200th iteration (so no need for 100,000
  epochs!).    Don't get carried away though, this is a trivial problem
  and no    variation in the data set, so even with your lousy 6
  neurons, the    network basically memorizes what needs to be done.
  But this gives you    a great illustration of how it learns.

Other things to keep in mind and be careful about:

1. There is a `tf.one_hot()` function, so no need to do stuff manually
2. Your learning rate of 0.7 is generally too high. Seems OK for this problem but in other cases your optimizer will be jumping back
   and forth too much with that rate, just keep that in mind.

So I added just a few tweaks to your code. Here's what it looks like. I think this should be OK:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#increased the number of epoch
epochs = 1000
step = 5
# For eq100tion y = b + 0.1, sample data below
myImportedDatax1_np = np.array([[.1],[.1],[.2],[.2],[.3],[.3],[.4],[.4],[.1],[.1],[.2],[.2],],dtype=float)
myImportedDatax2_np = np.array([[.1],[.2],[.1],[.2],[.3],[.4],[.3],[.4],[.3],[.4],[.3],[.4]],dtype=float)
combined_Imported_Data_x = np.append(myImportedDatax1_np, myImportedDatax2_np, axis=1)
myImportedDatay_np = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],dtype=int)

number_unique_labels = myImportedDatay_np.max()+1
myImportedDatay_np_one_hot = np.zeros((myImportedDatay_np.size, number_unique_labels))

myImportedDatay_np_one_hot[np.arange(myImportedDatay_np.size),myImportedDatay_np] = 1

print('x {}\n{}\n*****'.format(combined_Imported_Data_x.shape, combined_Imported_Data_x))
print('y {}\n{}\n*****'.format(myImportedDatay_np_one_hot.shape, myImportedDatay_np_one_hot))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2], name='x')

y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, number_unique_labels], name='y_true')

nodes_Hidden_Layer_1 = 6
number_Inputs = 2
number_Outputs = 3

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([number_Inputs, nodes_Hidden_Layer_1], stddev=0.03), name='W1')
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes_Hidden_Layer_1]), name='b1')
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes_Hidden_Layer_1, number_Outputs], stddev=0.03), name='W2')
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([number_Outputs]), name='b2')

hidden_out = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W1), b1)
hidden_out = tf.nn.relu(hidden_out)

y_ = (tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_out, W2), b2))
ys = tf.nn.softmax(y_, name='ys')
pred = tf.argmax(ys, axis=1)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_))

optimiser = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.7).minimize(cost)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # initialise the variables
    sess.run(init_op)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        _, cost_now, p = sess.run([optimiser, cost, pred], {x: combined_Imported_Data_x, y_true: myImportedDatay_np_one_hot})
        if epoch % step == 0:
            print('Step {}, Predictions: {}'.format(epoch, p))
```

Comment: Cannot say how much I appreciate your answer. The main problem is that I am looking at tensorflow as a black box, rather than the fundamental NN equations (which I studied carefully based on sigmoids!!). Feel silly, but at least enlightened.